# How can I add x-forwarded-for in Apache error log file?

Tags: apache-2.2

I have 2 servers with Apache 2.2 and LB (NetScaler),

I can see the client IP by using x-forwarded-for in access log but I do not see it in error log,

Is there any way to add x-forwarded-for in error log file?

Answer (score 5):

In apache 2.2 you cannot change the error log format like ThatGremeGuy mentioned and his solution would be the best.

In 2.4 you can change it

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#errorlog

Comment: Didn't realise there was a new ErrorLogFormat in 2.4, thanks.

Comment: Your answer is the way to go in 2.2 which he said was the version.. I was just putting it out there in case others came and running 2.4

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the format of the error log, but you can use [mod_rpaf](http://stderr.net/apache/rpaf/) to log the client IP instead of the proxy (LB) IP.